# How can I influence the owning group of files in /var/log/upstart?

Tags: upstart

upstart supports a setgid stanza, but this has an influence only on the running process, not on the log file written by upstart itself.

So if the setuid and setgid stanzas are used, the service or any of its children cannot read its logfile, but I want it to be able to and am seeking for a clean way to do so, retaining the upstart logging mechanism.

chgrp in the script or post-start script stanzas does not help because these scripts are executed as the setuid user and thus have no permission.